# Нарисовать четырёхлепестковую розу по формуле (x^2+y^2)^3=4a^2x^2y^2

Tags: java, графика, jframe, java2d

Задали домашнее задание:
Условие:

1. Разработайте пользовательский класс Shape реализующий рисование
   указанной алгебраической линии.
2. Разработайте пользовательский класс Stroke для отображения
   указанного контура, используя в качестве исходных точек результаты
   класса Shape, созданного на шаге 1)
3. Создайте приложение (Frame/JFrame) для тестирования и
   демонстрации разработанных классов.

Всё бы ничего, но вот как построить именно розу не понимаю. Уравнение которым она задаётся, записано в неявном виде и просто так выразить `у` через `х` или наоборот не получается. Тут надо что-то другое. Помогите пожалуйста с идеей.... и если можно с реализацией)

Comment: в этой формуле есть `а`, это что?

Comment: Человек, который даже правильно формулу не может скопировать, помощи не заслужил.

Comment: Перейдите в полярные координаты

Answer (score 1):

Ну мое решение, конечно, хз как по качеству (нет класса shape и т.д.), но можешь проходиться по каждому пикселю, брать его х,у и при соблюдении равенства (x^2+y^2)^3 == 4a^2x^2y^2 заполнять этот пиксель (при желании можно и смежные) каким то цветом

Comment: решение как решение, имеет право на жизнь, только надо еще уметь применить масштаб